# Matplotlib WSL2 Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, ubuntu, pycharm, wsl-2

I am using the Python 3.8.5 interpreter which is located on WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04. The system itself runs on Windows 10. The problem is that matplotlib does not draw a graph. I use PyCharm as IDE. Tell me please. how can i solve this problem?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(np.array([1,2,3,4,1]))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not yet supported in PyCharm: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-42827 (and they have no plans yet as to when they're going to fix this).

Answer (score 1):

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WebAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

This is helpful for me.
It will start a web page in where show the picture.